# Cannot build for simulator with iphonesimulator9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode7.2

I am facing weird errors when trying to build my project for the simulator with xcodebuild (It works fine when building directly with Xcode).

```
09:54:55 - tito@lt0311 Game> xcrun xcodebuild -verbose -scheme Game -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos9.2 -derivedDataPath builds clean build | xcpretty
▸ Cleaning Game/Game [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Clean Succeeded
▸ Building Game/Game [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Compiling AppDelegate.m
▸ Compiling main.m
▸ Compiling ViewController.m
▸ Compiling ViewController.m
▸ Compiling AppDelegate.m
▸ Compiling main.m
▸ Compiling Main.storyboard
▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Touching Game.app
▸ Signing builds/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Game.app
▸ Build Succeeded

09:55:06 - tito@lt0311 Game> xcrun xcodebuild -verbose -scheme Game -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 -derivedDataPath builds clean build | xcpretty
▸ Cleaning Game/Game [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Clean Succeeded
▸ Building Game/Game [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Compiling ViewController.m

❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture

#error Unsupported architecture
 ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: architecture not supported

#error architecture not supported
 ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: unknown type name '__int64_t'

typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean 'uint64_t'?

typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'

typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
                           ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: unknown type name '__uint16_t'

typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: unknown type name '__int64_t'

typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:9: unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'

typedef __darwin_intptr_t       intptr_t;
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:42:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:9: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'; did you mean '__darwin_ino_t'?

typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t; 
        ^



❌  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKitDefines.h:8:9: could not build module 'Darwin'

#import <Availability.h>
                         ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <sys/types.h>
 ~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <sys/types.h>      // for __DARWIN_NULL
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/mach-o/arch.h:32:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <stdint.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:25:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/os/base.h:24:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <sys/cdefs.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:32:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:8:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <stdbool.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImageDefines.h:10:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CoreVideo.h:16:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTDefines.h:12:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:11:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <stdbool.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h:8:10: could not build module 'Foundation'

#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Users/tito/Documents/workspace/Game/Game/ViewController.h:9:9: could not build module 'UIKit'

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^


▸ Compiling AppDelegate.m

❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:707:2: Unsupported architecture

#error Unsupported architecture
 ~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: architecture not supported

#error architecture not supported
 ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: unknown type name '__int64_t'

typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
 ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
                     ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean 'uint64_t'?

typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
                     ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'

typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
                           ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean 'uint16_t'?

typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: unknown type name '__int64_t'

typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
                       ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: unknown type name '__int32_t'

typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
                     ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean 'uint32_t'?

typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
                     ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_intptr_t.h:30:9: unknown type name '__darwin_intptr_t'

typedef __darwin_intptr_t       intptr_t;
                     ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:9: unknown type name '__darwin_size_t'

typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t; 
        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_ct_rune_t.h:31:9: unknown type name '__darwin_ct_rune_t'; did you mean '__darwin_wctrans_t'?

typedef __darwin_ct_rune_t ct_rune_t;
        ^



❌  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKitDefines.h:8:9: could not build module 'Darwin'

#import <Availability.h>
                        ^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <sys/types.h>
 ~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:31:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <sys/types.h>      // for __DARWIN_NULL
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/mach-o/arch.h:32:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <stdint.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:25:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/usr/include/os/base.h:24:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <sys/cdefs.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:32:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:8:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <stdbool.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImageDefines.h:10:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CoreVideo.h:16:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTDefines.h:12:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:11:10: could not build module 'Darwin'

#include <stdbool.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h:8:10: could not build module 'Foundation'

#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^



❌  /Users/tito/Documents/workspace/Game/Game/AppDelegate.h:9:9: could not build module 'UIKit'

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^


▸ Compiling main.m
▸ Compiling AppDelegate.m
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC builds/Build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphoneos/Game.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.o Game/ViewController.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC builds/Build/Intermediates/Game.build/Debug-iphoneos/Game.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate.o Game/AppDelegate.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

This commands have been executed on a project that I had just created with Xcode7.2.

Does anyone know how to solve these errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround is to specify the destination parameter when building -

```
xcodebuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -workspace "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -sdk iphonesimulator  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"  **-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=DC050A0D-6041-40F5-9D0E-EAEFA1D1EA42,OS=9.2'** clean build
```

(Replace the "id" with name such as name=iPhone 6 if you have only one simulator of that specific type)

Comment: So it's a bug in XCode 7.2 or something else ?

Answer (score 9):

On the apple forums user inside found another workaround:

> Pass `PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator` to `xcodebuild`, in addition to
>   `-sdk iphonesimulator`.

By this way you're not related to simulator name or id.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27975